# Android after selecting file from storage my app closes automatically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read csv file from storage but when file chooser dialog opens and I select file my app automatically closes, I am running android 11 and I have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file also I ask user for runtime permission. No exception or error is shown when my app closes.

Edit: It seems that `activityResultLauncher` is not getting called

Below is my code:

```
package com.suyogbauskar.attenteachers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.suyogbauskar.attenteachers.pojos.StudentData;
import com.suyogbauskar.attenteachers.pojos.UnitTestMarks;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;

public class UnitTestMarksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button uploadBtn;
private int selectedSemester;
private FirebaseUser user;
private TableLayout table;
private boolean isFirstRow;
private String subjectCodeTeacher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_unit_test_marks);
    setTitle("Unit Test Marks");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    findAllViews();
    uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> uploadFile());
}

private void findAllViews() {
    uploadBtn = findViewById(R.id.uploadBtn);
}

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(UnitTestMarksActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
);

private void uploadFile() {
    Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    data.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
    data = Intent.createChooser(data, "Choose unit test marks");
    activityResultLauncher.launch(data);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AttenTeachers"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".UnitTestMarksActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:noHistory="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below gif shows how my app closes:

[image: Gif showing how my app closes]

Comment: Did you check your logcat ? no error printed ?

Comment: I checked logcat no error is shown

Comment: can you add your manifest file here

Comment: I updated my question and added `AndroidManifest.xml`